# lateinit property dManager has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

I have a variable in my fragment class:

```
private lateinit var dManager: DataManager
```

And I'm initializing it before the first using here:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    dManager = MyApp.gManager.getDataManager(sp,level,test)
    if (dManager.hp< 1) { 
       ...
       ...
       ...
    }
}
```

This code works ok for me and most users (99.5%), but sometimes i get crash report

> lateinit property dManager has not been initialized

How can this happen? What should I do to prevent it?

Comment: Guess it means that `MyApp.gManager.getDataManager` returns `null`. Why can this happen? Well, that depends on how you're initializing it O_o

Comment: @EpicPandaForce You'd get a different error message in this case, I believe. I'd look for other uses of `dManager` instead and if they can ever happen before `onResume`.

Answer (score 1):

**lateinit var makes compiler aware that’s not null**

1. If your property is lifecycle-driven (e.g. a reference to a TextView
   or ImageView which gets inflated during Android Activity lifecycle)
   or it is initialized through injection, you cannot supply a non-null
   initializer and you must declare its type as nullable.  This in turn
   will require you to use null checks every time you reference the
   property, which may be a bit inconvenient, especially if you are
   absolutely sure the property will get initialized at some point,
   before you access it for the first time.
2. **Kotlin** has a simple solution for such a scenario, allowing you to mark the property with the lateinit modifier.
3. If you access the property before initialization, you’ll get
   an **UninitializedPropertyAccessException**.

**getDataManager(sp,level,test)** may return sometimes null so for safe sides your  solution would be like as :-

```
override fun onResume() {
super.onResume()
dManager = MyApp.gManager.getDataManager(sp,level,test)
if (::dbManager.isInitialized && dManager.hp< 1) { 
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your `getDataManager(sp,level,test)` return `null` value

**OR**

As per the document you have to check object with `.isInitialized` property.

```
Returns true if this lateinit property has been assigned a value, and false otherwise.
```

[Check lateinit var is initialized](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#checking-whether-a-lateinit-var-is-initialized)

```
lateinit var file: File    

if (::file.isInitialized) { ... }
```